# How can I be able to pass the data in the textbox into the gridview after clicking submit button(

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, webforms

When I click the submit button,I cannot see the data in the gridview.What changes do I need to make in order to see the data in the GridView?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           DataTable table = new DataTable();
           table.Columns.Add("ProductId");
           table.Columns.Add("ProductName");
           table.Columns.Add("ExpiryDate");
           table.Columns.Add("Price");
           table.Columns.Add("LotNumber");
           DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
           dr["ProductId"] = ProductId.Text;
           dr["ProductName"] = ProductName.Text;
           dr["ExpiryDate"] = ExpiryDate.Text;
           dr["Price"] = Price.Text;
           dr["LotNumber"] = LotNumber.Text;
           table.Rows.Add(dr);
           GridView2.DataSource = table;
           GridView2.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Your code should work. What is the problem?

Comment: @MortalKombat 1. Post your markup (your aspx or ascx). 2. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Did you check that this code is executed? meaning it is the right event handler. In addition, did you verified that you are updating the right GridView? It looks you have two of them.

Comment: Yeah,Sorry it worked.I updated  the wrong GridView.It should have been GridView1 instead of GridView2.Thank you @KernalMode.

Comment: If this problem is solved then delete this post

Answer (score 0):

According the code, you have two `GridView`. Verify you update the right one.